# What is the correct way of asking, How are Mom and Dad?, or How are Uncle and Aunt?

Tags: meaning, grammar, vocabulary, questions

While Chatting when you have to ask your friend, how are your mom and dad? Which is the correct way of asking How are Mom and Dad?, or How are Uncle and Aunt? or simply How are your mom and dad?

Comment: Plural: "How are A and B?"

Comment: "How are your mom and dad?"

Comment: Sorry for that silly error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the pluralization error pointed out by aparente001 (It should be how *are* A and B, not how *is* A and B), this is up to you.
So long as you don't add possessive pronouns, as below, the sentence is just inherently ambiguous.

The sentence can be made less ambiguous by the use of a pronoun.

> How are *my* Mom and Dad?
>
> How are *your* Uncle and Aunt?

Although it is now far less eloquent in my opinion.

Without the pronouns, it is entirely up to you.
Less formally, when speaking to a child, it might be more appropriate to refer to the persons from the perspective of the child (i.e. Aunt and Uncle in your example). Whereas I would find it entirely inappropriate for a work acquaintance to refer to *my* parents as "Mom and Dad" instead of "your parents" or similar. Of course, that does not make it semantically wrong.

Comment: If the downvoter(s) could comment on any problems there might be in my answer, that would be of great value.